# CLI stopped working composer trying to install laravel Mamp

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, mamp

I installed composer using the MAMP PHP 5.6.8 php.exe. I first ran into the OpenSSL.dll issue. I fixed that by copying the MAMP/conf/php5.6.8/php.ini and pasting it in MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.8 so composer wouldn't ask for the OpenSSL.

I opened up command prompt and cd to my MAMP htdocs.
I ran `composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel_project`.
So this is what I saw in the command prompt[image]

Once it started installing the dependencies this came up.
[image]

Can someone please help me find a solution to this odd problem. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried restarting computer and running command again with same output?

Comment: Yes I restarted my computer and it does the same thing.

Comment: Try piping standard out to a file, you might get more details on what error is happening.

Comment: Try running command with high verbosity `-vvv`, to get more debug details.

Comment: I couldn't find out why it didn't work for mamp. I moved to wamp and right away it worked. It is odd that has never happened to me before

Comment: Could you mark your answer as solution then? So it can be easily spotted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MAMP and have the same issue and this fixed it for me:

Look for php.ini in MAMP\bin\php[php_version], then uncomment opache extension. Basically, change:

```
;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
```

to:

```
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
```

I hope that helps.

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3604